# Checkboxes Alignment

Tags: android

I want to achieve 5 checkboxes in a row and 3 such rows one below the other.
Attach is the image.
[image]

How to do it using CheckBox, LinearLayout and TableRow?
All checkboxes are dynamically created using String array and not inside layout xml file.

I tried the following:

```
int i = 0; 
while(i < 15) { 
  TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); 
  CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[5]; 
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++,i++) { 
       cb[j] = new CheckBox(this); cb[j].setText(arrLetters[i]);
       cb[j].setHeight(80); 
       cb[j].setWidth(250); 
       cb[j].setId(i); 
       tr.addView(cb[j]); 
  } 
  linearLayout.addView(tr);
```

abhishek

Comment: I tried following, bit could not achieve

Comment: int i = 0;
            while(i < 15) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

                CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[5];
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++,i++) {
                    cb[j] = new CheckBox(this);
                    cb[j].setText(arrLetters[i]);
                    cb[j].setHeight(80);
                    cb[j].setWidth(250);
                    cb[j].setId(i);
     
                    tr.addView(cb[j]);
                }
      
                linearLayout.addView(tr);

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You need fixed 5 checkboxes at each row or wrap depending on screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a `TableRow` to achieve that. You can use `LinearLayout` like this:

1. Create **1** *Horizontal* `LinearLayout`.
2. Add **5** *Vertical* `LinearLayout`s to the horizontal layout.
3. Add **3** `CheckBox`es to each *Vertical* layout.
4. Set the *weight* of each vertical layout to **1**.
5. Set the *weight* of each `CheckBox` to **1**.

**Example**

Creating `LinearLayout` dynamically:

```
LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
// specifying vertical or horizontal orientation
linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
// creating LayoutParams  
LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
```

Creating `CheckBox` and adding it to the `LinearLayout` dynamically:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
// add other attributes like id and Params for the weight..etc
linLayout.addView(checkBox, linLayoutParam);
```

---

**Working Implementation (*Example*)**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
        horizontalLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        setContentView(horizontalLayout, layoutParams);

        int[] colors = new int[]{ Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN};

        LinearLayout [] columns = new LinearLayout[5];
        for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
            LinearLayout verticalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            verticalLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            verticalLayout.setId(i);
            verticalLayout.setBackgroundColor(colors[i]);
            columns[i] = verticalLayout;
            horizontalLayout.addView(verticalLayout, layoutParams);
        }

        String[] checkBoxesNames = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
                                                "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"};

        CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[checkBoxesNames.length];
        for(int i=0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++){
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            checkBox.setText(checkBoxesNames[i].toString());
            checkBox.setId(i);
            checkBox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            if(i%5==0) {columns[0].addView(checkBox, layoutParams);} // column 0
            if(i%5==1) {columns[1].addView(checkBox, layoutParams);} // column 1
            if(i%5==2) {columns[2].addView(checkBox, layoutParams);} // column 2
            if(i%5==3) {columns[3].addView(checkBox, layoutParams);} // column 3
            if(i%5==4) {columns[4].addView(checkBox, layoutParams);} // column 4
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** **[Colors only for Demonstration Purpose!]**

[image]

---

**Note** that the above is just an example but you can manipulate the *Vertical* `LinearLayout` (i.e. columns) the way it fits your application, for example: if I change the Params from `MATCH_PARENT` to `WRAP_CONTENT` or if I set specific dimensions, it will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**JAVA CODE**

```
    LinearLayout ll_Main = findViewById(R.id.root_lay); //Root Layout in XML File

    /*Custom Layout*/

    LinearLayout root_Layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    root_Layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams root_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    root_Layout.setLayoutParams(root_Params);

    LinearLayout root_Base1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    root_Base1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams base_Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    base_Params1.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    root_Base1.setLayoutParams(base_Params1);
    root_Base1.setWeightSum(5.0f);

    CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox(this);
    box1.setText("A");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box1_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box1_Params.weight = 1;
    box1.setLayoutParams(box1_Params);

    CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox(this);
    box2.setText("B");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box2_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box2_Params.weight = 1;
    box2.setLayoutParams(box1_Params);

    CheckBox box3 = new CheckBox(this);
    box3.setText("C");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box3_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box3_Params.weight = 1;
    box3.setLayoutParams(box1_Params);

    CheckBox box4 = new CheckBox(this);
    box4.setText("D");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box4_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box4_Params.weight = 1;
    box4.setLayoutParams(box1_Params);

    CheckBox box5 = new CheckBox(this);
    box5.setText("E");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box5_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box5_Params.weight = 1;
    box5.setLayoutParams(box1_Params);

    root_Base1.addView(box1);
    root_Base1.addView(box2);
    root_Base1.addView(box3);
    root_Base1.addView(box4);
    root_Base1.addView(box5);
    root_Layout.addView(root_Base1);

    LinearLayout root_Base2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    root_Base2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams base_Params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    base_Params2.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
    root_Base2.setLayoutParams(base_Params2);
    root_Base2.setWeightSum(5.0f);

    CheckBox box6 = new CheckBox(this);
    box6.setText("F");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box6_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box6_Params.weight = 1;
    box6.setLayoutParams(box6_Params);

    CheckBox box7 = new CheckBox(this);
    box7.setText("G");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box7_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box7_Params.weight = 1;
    box7.setLayoutParams(box7_Params);

    CheckBox box8 = new CheckBox(this);
    box8.setText("H");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box8_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box8_Params.weight = 1;
    box8.setLayoutParams(box8_Params);

    CheckBox box9 = new CheckBox(this);
    box9.setText("I");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box9_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box9_Params.weight = 1;
    box9.setLayoutParams(box9_Params);

    CheckBox box10 = new CheckBox(this);
    box10.setText("J");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams box10_Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    box10_Params.weight = 1;
    box10.setLayoutParams(box10_Params);

    root_Base2.addView(box6);
    root_Base2.addView(box7);
    root_Base2.addView(box8);
    root_Base2.addView(box9);
    root_Base2.addView(box10);
    root_Layout.addView(root_Base2);

    ll_Main.addView(root_Layout);

    /*Custom Layout*/
```